# Codeiniter3, MySQL5, AES_ENCRYPT Max Key Length

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cryptography, aes

I've recently come to work on a project that is half built using Codeigniter3. I've come to this interesting question.

So due to GDPR rules in the EU they have decided to encrypt person identifiable fields like name, email and etc..

These fields are encrypted using AES and more specifically mysql native function AES_ENCRYPT(field, key) and decrypted using AES_DECRYPT(fields, key). which works fine

However I've noticed that the key is 96 chars long :O, which according to MySQL documentation can only be 32Chars.

I was trying to understand how this is not throwing an error. I've seen in the mysql docs about this encryption that it would ignore anything longer than 16 bytes so taken a copy of the key partially (upto 16chars) to see if it would ignore the rest but then the encrypted data won't load which means it needs the full key

There's no hashing being done with the key

sample insert query

```
insert into customers (email) values (AES_ENCRYPT('".$email."', '".$key."')
```

Sample Select

```
AES_DECRYPT(firstname, "'.KEY.'") as firstName,
```

How does this not throw an error

Thanks in advance

Comment: the key length differs depending on the server mode, also mysql only uses the bits confgrued, so you can increase the key till the max string size.  but your code loks like it is **vulnerable to sql injection** please read up on **prepared statements with parameters**

Comment: Would you be able to give me a link to some more reading about this. Also thanks for the note about sql inkjection

Comment: i don't which link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt descryptes everything, not explicit the size of the key as you want to know, but it can be  more than 128 bit, but what happens to the key that is bigger , isn't mentioned, you could always look in the code, the reszt aber servermodes are linked